# why does Mobiledetect.net script not detect iPhone?

Tags: php, android, ios, iphone, mobile-devices

I am trying to detect the device using this script `http://mobiledetect.net/`
but it's not detecting iPhone.

**header.php:**

```
<?php
require_once 'include/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect; ?>
```

**device.php:**

```
<?php include 'include/header.php'; ?>
<?php if( $detect->isMobile() && $detect->isTablet() ){ ?>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    alert("I am mobile");
</script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    alert("I am desktop");
</script>
<? } ?>
```

When I check the page on desktop I am getting popup with this message: `I am desktop` - As I expected

When I check the page on android tablet I am getting popup with this message: `I am mobile` - As I expected

When I check the page on iPhone I am getting popup with this message: `I am desktop` - NOT as expected.

Why is this?

Here is the [PAGE](http://responsive.olankatravels.com/arnold/device.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're asking whether the browser is running on a mobile device **and** (&&) on a tablet:

`$detect->isMobile() && $detect->isTablet()`

Due to the second condition, this is only true for tablets, not for phones. Just remove it if you want the condition to be true for any mobile device:

`<?php if( $detect->isMobile() ){ ?>`